# multiple Search parameters in Multiple joined tables using LINQ in DBML

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to build an `advanced multiple parameters search` for a website.
This is my DBML and ORM schema:
[image]
In this `advanced multiple parameters search` user can search through Estates with multiple parameters as like size, floor, city, price and so on.
This is the function that I coded to handle this part.

```
 private DataTable linq_search_by_details()
    {
        myDBMLDataContext ctx = new myDBMLDataContext(address);
        var query = ctx.Estates.AsQueryable();
        query = query.Where(c => c.eshId == int.Parse(ddlEshape.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        query = query.Where(c => c.cityId == int.Parse(ddlcity.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        query = query.Where(c => c.ETId == int.Parse(ddlType.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        query = query.Where(c => c.dealingId == int.Parse(ddldeal.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        query = query.Where(c => c.deedId == int.Parse(ddldeed.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrepaymentFrom.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.prepayment) <= int.Parse(txtPrepaymentFrom.Value));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrepaymentTo.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.prepayment) >= int.Parse(txtPrepaymentTo.Value));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrepaymentFrom.Value.Trim()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrepaymentTo.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.prepayment) <= int.Parse(txtPrepaymentFrom.Value) && int.Parse(c.prepayment) >= int.Parse(txtPrepaymentTo.Value));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPriceFrom.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.price) <= int.Parse(txtPriceFrom.Value));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPriceTo.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.price) >= int.Parse(txtPriceTo.Value));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPriceFrom.Value.Trim()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPriceTo.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => int.Parse(c.price) <= int.Parse(txtPriceFrom.Value) && int.Parse(c.price) >= int.Parse(txtPriceTo.Value));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFloor.Value.Trim()))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.eFloor == short.Parse(txtFloor.Value));
        }
        if (chbExchange.Checked)
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.exchange == true);
        }

        var final = query.Select(c => new { c.esId,c.owId, c.City.cityName, c.EstateShape.eshName, c.EstateType.ETName, c.owner.owFname, c.owner.owLname, c.esSize, c.prepayment, c.price });
        return Special.LINQResultToDataTable(final.ToList());
}
```

This function works perfectly but now I want more to add some parameres from `EstateEquipment` and `EstateFacility`.
As you can see in `ORM` the relation between `Estate` and `EstateEquipment` (also `Estate` and `EstateFacility`) is `one to many`.

 Now I want to user can search through Estate in `cityId = 1`, `size around 400m` which has for example `eqId = 1 and 2` from `EstateEquipment` then which has for example `fId = 1 and 2` from `EstateFacility`.
This is how I tried to handle last part.

```
foreach (ListItem item in cblEquipment.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        eq = true;
    }
}
if(eq)
{
    var eqQuery = ctx.EstateEquipments.AsQueryable();
    foreach (ListItem item in cblEquipment.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            eqQuery = eqQuery.Where(c => c.eqId == int.Parse(item.Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
    var eqFinal = eqQuery.Select(c => new { c.Estate.esId, c.Estate.owner.owId, c.Estate.City.cityName, c.Estate.EstateShape.eshName, c.Estate.EstateType.ETName, c.Estate.owner.owFname, c.Estate.owner.owLname, c.Estate.esSize, c.Estate.prepayment, c.Estate.price });
    DataTable dtEq = Special.LINQResultToDataTable(eqFinal.ToList());
    if(dtEq.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        this.Build_search(dtEq);
    }
    else
    {
        msg = "No record found";
        sysMsg.Attributes["class"] = "";
        sysMsg.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-warning";
    }
}
```

Here, First I check which equipment is selected from the list. Then extended the query accordance with Items selected. But I don't know how to join this new result with last result and even `EstateFacility` result.
**Thanks for any help.**

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to test my solution because of your rather complex case, I hope it at least puts you in the right direction.

I'd say try something like this:

```
    if (cblEquipment.Items.Any(item => item.Selected))
    {
        var selectedEquipmentIds = cblEquipment.Items.Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => int.Parse(item.Value.ToString()));
        query = query.Where(c => ctx.EstateEquipments.Any(eq => eq.esId == c.esId && selectedEquipmentIds.Contains(eq.eqId)));
    }
```

This goes in your first code snippet just before `var final ...`. Second snippet will then not be used and therefore your error handling over there will also need to move...

Comment: Agree. When chaining predicates this way, it's always easiest to keep adding predicates rooted in the query root entity.

Comment: thanks for the advice but would you test your code. don't need to implement all of the code. just small part and share it with others here. Thanks a lot